# How can I tell on the master record if it has been cloned

Tags: clone

Is there a way to identify, with a checkbox for example, if a record has been cloned.  I need to identify this on the master record, not on the record copy.  I see there is the ISCLONE() but this looks like it will only work with the copy.

Comment: I don't think you can, you would have to go back and edit the record after the clone or on the cloned record have a link back to the original.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to write Apex Code then you can write a trigger where on insert you can check if an object is cloned (via the isClone() function on sObject) and then use the getCloneSourceId() function (on sObject) to find the originator and set a checkbox to true on that object.

Reference to the functions:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm?search_text=SObject

Comment: I don't think this method will help the OP solve the problem they are trying to.